# How can I add sum of Email ID with there CreatedDate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get `SUM` of `Email ID` with there `CreatedDate` in SQL Server, as I have two columns in table, I have `EMailID` as `varchar`, `CreatedDate` as `datetime` and I need the sum of counts of emailid.

As example table listed below.

```
Email ID          createddate
-----------------------------------------    
xyz1@gmail.com    2014-09-19 19:19:36.007
xyz2@gmail.com    2014-09-19 19:19:36.007    


Count          Createddate
---------------------------       
2              2014-09-19
```

Comment: Since it's not a numerical value, you cannot really **sum** it - what you want is the **COUNT** of e-mail Id's ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    COUNT(Email) as Count_Mails, 
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Createddate)) 
from 
    tblUser
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Createddate))
```

Answer (score 1):

You Use `Count` with `Group BY`

```
select COUNT(EmailID) as Count_Mails, CAST(Createddate as DATE)
GROUP BY  cast(createdDate as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table MyTable(
    EmailId varchar(100),
    CreatedDate datetime
)
insert into MyTable values
('xyz1@gmail.com', '2014-09-19 19:19:36.007'),
('xyz1@gmail.com', '2014-09-19 19:19:36.007'),
('xyz3@gmail.com', '2014-09-19 19:20:36.007')
```

## SOLUTION

```
select
    EmailId = count(EmailId),
    CreatedDate = cast(createdDate as date)
from MyTable
group by cast(createdDate as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the number of `emailids` created on a date then try this :

```
select cast(CreatedDate as date) as dt, Count(emailid)
from   yourtable
group  by cast(CreatedDate as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Count(EmailID) as Count_Email ,Cast(Createddate as Date) 
from table 
group by Createddate
```